# adding html to the headers

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am saving something in doc but it adds html to it

```
<?

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo 'hi';

?>
```

and it shows hi in doc file but then the complete html of the page. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why wouldn't it show the HTML of the page if that's what you're outputting at some point?

Comment: why negative? I wanted to know how to take html off! thanks though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

this did it